# Java + Sqlite and 64Bit Issue?

Tags: java, macos, sqlite, 64-bit

i develop an java desktop application which consome sqlite database. (My pc, windows 7 and 32Bit intel processor.) And, i want to run this application into Mac Book or other mac types (intel based on etc..). Is this application working properly into mac book?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAOt1.png

Comment: Are you asking if it will work or are you saying that it is actually working and that confuses you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a JDBC driver that connects to the native code. The JDBC part will work, but you need to have native code for each and every processor/OS combination. So no, the 32 bit code won't work at all. (and would be for the wrong os anyway).

Remember the only magic OS independent part is the java part. Native code is native code